# View Containing Subquery doesn't show in DataMember

Tags: c#, data-binding, datasource, strongly-typed-dataset

In Below image a View is showing in DataSources.

[image: Data Source]

In Below image Same DataSource is shown in Data Set Design View
[image: DataSet]

After drag and drop of Same **DataSource** on form as Grid **DataMember** property of same Grid is not showing the name in its list.
[image: Data Members]

**Propertis of Grid**
[image: Grid Propery]

**Properties of Binding Source**
[image]

---

**Script of the View is**

```
ALTER View [dbo].[V_CustomerBalance] as
SELECT M.Sales_id,
       M.Sales_date, 
       M.Customer_id, 
       M.Total_Weight, 
       M.Total_Amount, 
       M.Is_fully_paid, 
       SP.New_SrNo, 
       SP.Total_Amount_Paid,
       (M.Total_Amount - SP.Total_Amount_Paid) AS Due_Amount
  FROM SalesMasterTable AS M ,
       (SELECT P.Sales_id, 
               MAX(P.Sr_no) + 1 AS New_SrNo, 
               SUM(P.Amount_paid) AS Total_Amount_Paid
          FROM SalesPaymentTable AS P
         GROUP BY P.Sales_id
        HAVING MIN(P.Amount_due) > 0) AS SP 
 WHERE M.Sales_id = SP.Sales_id
GO
```

---

My problem is, should the view present in data source be present in data member as well.

I think its Yes.
If not then why?

Comment: Did you have created the view after creating data source? If so you must refresh the data source.

Comment: Did the same but did not helped.

Comment: What have you set as datagrid data source?

Comment: When I Drag and Droped then automatically it creates a new binding source. That BindingSource is DataSource of grid. DataSource of that bindingsource is Typed DataSet. Data Member of Bindingsource and Grid are empty.

Comment: You must set the data source of datagridview to BindingSource .

Comment: Yes its already there. I modified my question and shown in the image.

Comment: Why you set the datasource of bindingsource to jvellKongdonDataSet?

Comment: It automatically takes.

Comment: I cannot see the Images anyone can see them?

Comment: Romesh do you still need assistance?

Comment: @dmportella I have not yet tried ur solution, But surely I will check this one. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times is simpler to go back to basics.

Firstly your data grid view should be using as its data source a binding source component.

The data member of the GridView should be empty with only the data source selected (to the binding source).

If you follow the steps below you will get a working copy of a grid view using a sql view.

1. Create a new DataSet in the solution and add your View to it.
2. Open the Form where your Grid resides.
3. On the context menu for the dataset set the data source to the typed Dataset in your solution.

This should create three components on you form.

1. DataSet Component.
2. A BindingSource attached to your DataSet Component.
3. A Custom Table Adapter that comes from you In Solution data set.

Your grid view will have its data source attached to the Binding source. The binding source DataSource will be set to the DataSet Component in the form and its DataMember will display the view name. The Gridview should not display anything on the DataMember property as it will be getting all the data and information from the binding source.

**In your code your binging source data member property should be set to the view name.**

I hope this helps.